# How to partially update a graph after adding element?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I draw a graph from a set of nodes and links using the following update function with nodes and links arrays defined earlier in the code.

```
      function update() {
          var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
          .data(links);
          link.enter().insert("line")
            .attr("class", "link");

          var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
          .data(nodes);
          node.enter().append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("id", function(d) { return d.name })
              .on("dblclick", dblclick)
              .on("mouseover", function(d) {drawTags(tags, d.name);})
              .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                  d3.select("#"+d.name).selectAll(".tool")
                    .transition()
                    .delay(800)
                    .remove();
                  })
              .call(force.drag);

              node.append("circle")
              .attr("class", "circle")
              .attr("r", 40);

              // display name in nodes if node structure
              node.append("text")
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

              force.on("tick", function() {
                       link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                       .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                       .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                       .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
                       node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                                 return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                                 });
                       });
           force.start();
      }
```

On dynamic update of the graph, after double click event on a node, I fetch additional nodes and links and display them. So far, I was able to append nodes and links to their corresponding arrays, hence update drawing. However, the update function would loop through all elements for the display.

Therefore I would like to pass newNodes and newEdges to the update function and only draw new elements. The issue is that new elements replace existing ones in the svg code rather than to be appended.

Is there a way to append new elements to previously existing ones in the drawing?
Full code is available on fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/pducrot/4eyb81kx/) mouse over a node and click on any appearing tag to see what's happening.

Comment: For the force layout, you need to modify the underlying data structure (i.e. the nodes and links).

Comment: What do you mean by this? nodes and links are initialized by force.nodes() and force.links(). Hence I push actual nodes and links to the arrays and used those for node decorations. I was expecting that push additional nodes and links to these two arrays and hence decorating the new items would work. Do you mean that I should always loop through all items and redecorate existing ones?

Comment: See the "Modying..." section in [this tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/d3-force-layout-internals). You also need to compute and handle the enter/update/exit selections in the `tick` handler function.

Comment: If I understand correctly you tutorial, once new nodes and links have been pushed to the corresponding arrays, I should call update() with no parameters and perform decoration referring to nodes and links using  force.links() and force.nodes(). I was expecting to be able to only decorate new items.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "decorate". The general idea is that you handle changes in the data in the `tick` handler function through enter/update/exit selections. This way all you need to do is modify the underlying data -- if the force layout is still running the changes will be picked up automatically and there's no need to call a separate function.

Comment: By decorate I meant creating line, circles, etc. which is the purpose of the update() function. It seems to work better from your suggestion. I'm still learning. I'll post my code once improved, you may have addition suggestions.